# How to recover lists that are saved in Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have lists inside a Series, which are stored inside a Dataframe. Now i want to recreate these lists. How can I do that? I try to call them with a function. As example:

```
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ....)
    getList (df.ix[1,['column']])
```

So how can it get now back again a list with multiple elements? the tolist() method returns the whole list as one element.

```
    In: pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]]).tolist()
    Out: [[1, 2, 3]]
```

In a short way. How can i access each element of a list, that is stored inside a Series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iloc[0]` gets you the first element of the series, which is a list.  `[0]` gets the first element of that list.

```
pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]]).iloc[0][0]
```

Or:

```
pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]]).tolist()[0][0]
```

You can also do:

```
pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]]).apply(lambda x: x[2])
```

To get all 3rd elements as a series.

```
0    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's what I've been lookiung for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the original list back form a `Pandas Series' then 'totlist()` should work fine. If this is what you mean, because your question is not really clear.
Also, your `pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ....)` is not right, please see below:

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]])
s.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

And, if you want to get an element of the original `list`:

```
s[0]
[1, 2, 3]

s[0][0]
1
```

Comment: Yeah I want to get back the original list. The actual code i wrote is to complex and so i tried to give an easier example. Anyway, tolist() is not working for me and returns me a list with len() = 1 and all elements in one field. Is it important to know that the list had been stored inside a data frame?

Comment: First, in your post you have this: `pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ....)` this should result in an `error`. Your series should look like this: `pd.Series([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ....])`. Second, as you can see in my answer, `tolist()` works. Can you check what the difference is in your code?